# Accessing resources within a service (Android)

Tags: android, resources, intentservice

I'm a fairly new developer to android, so I get the feeling there's some property of services that I am overlooking. Please let me know.

Everything seems to be working just fine as far as services go. I have an IntentService class that looks like this:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService 
{
myClass myObject;
int test;

public MyIntentService() 
{
    super("MyIntentService");

    test = 12;
    myObject = new myClass(this, R.raw.file);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return new LocalBinder<MyIntentService>(this);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
}
```

The constructor for myClass accepts a Context, and then an int for the raw resource. If I call the constructor in an Activity class it works just fine. The service itself also seems to be working because if I comment out the object stuff, I can retrieve the test int no problem.

So what am I missing here?

Thank you very much!